# Vuetify form submit from keyboard is causing click in a different element instead

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, keyboard-events, vuetifyjs3

I am working on a two-step login form (similar to the design of Google's login form) - the user enters their email address on the first screen, and their password on the second screen. (This is to allow redirecting to an external authentication system for certain users, but that's not part of the question.) When on the second screen, the user's email address is shown in a "chip" element, with a "close" button that allows going back to the email entry screen.

I need the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the keyboard to be able to be used to log in without needing to click the Submit button.

Using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key works perfectly on the screen where the user enters their email address.

However, on the second screen for entering the password, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does not work. Instead, I can see in the Vue Dev Tools Timeline that it causes the `click:close` event to fire on the `<v-chip>` component that shows the user's email address.

Why is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key causing a click on the chip when it is pressed in the password field?

Here is the code for the component (with server-side API calls replaced with alerts):

(I tried to set this up as a Stack Snippet, but couldn't get it to work, so in addition to the code below, here is a [link to the Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).)

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-card class="mx-auto px-10 pb-9" width="450px" :loading="loading">
        <v-form ref="form" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
          <v-card-title class="text-center pt-12">Company Name</v-card-title>
          <v-card-title class="text-center headline"
            >{{ subtitle }}</v-card-title
          >
          <v-card-text class="text-center">
            <template v-if="showForm !== 2">
              <v-text-field
                autocomplete="username"
                label="Email Address"
                v-model.trim="email"
                name="email"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                type="email"
                :error-messages="errorMessage"
                :rules="[rules.required, rules.email]"
              />
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <!-- Hidden input to make password managers work properly. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands -->
              <input
                name="email"
                type="hidden"
                :value="email"
                autocomplete="username"
              />
              <v-chip
                variant="outlined"
                class="mb-6"
                closable
                @click:close="showForm = 1"
                prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
                >{{email}}</v-chip
              >
              <v-text-field
                label="Password"
                v-model="password"
                name="password"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                spellcheck="false"
                :append-inner-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                :autocomplete="showPassword ? 'off' : 'current-password'"
                :error-messages="errorMessage"
                :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                @click:append-inner="showPassword = !showPassword"
              />
            </template>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn v-if="showForm !== 3" @click="showForm = 3"
              >Forgot Password</v-btn
            >
            <v-btn v-if="showForm === 3" @click="showForm = 1">Log In</v-btn>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-btn variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit"
              >Submit</v-btn
            >
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-form>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

  const loading = ref(false)

  const email = ref('')
  const showForm = ref(1)
  const password = ref('')
  const showPassword = ref(false)

  const errorMessage = ref('')

  const subtitle = computed(() => {
    switch (showForm.value) {
      case 1:
        return 'Log In'
      case 2:
        return 'Log In'
      case 3:
        return 'Forgot Password'
    }
  })

  const rules = {
    required: value => !!value || 'An email address is required',
    email: value => {
      const pattern =
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      return pattern.test(value) || 'Please enter a valid email address'
    },
  }

  function submitForm() {
    switch (showForm.value) {
      case 1:
        alert('doing local login')
        showForm.value = 2
        break
      case 2:
        alert('logged in')
        break
      case 3:
        alert('sent password reset email')
        break
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a bug, it'll be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/commit/c287a29800999fd07e777852c057d18c5eeb6fdc